# Axial tilt of exoplanets

Tags: exoplanet

Some directly imaged exoplanets have had their rotation measured but has the axial tilt of any exoplanet been measured? If not, when might we get the first measurement of axial tilt of an exoplanet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06278, the "James Webb Space Telescope should be able to constrain the obliquities of nearby warm Jupiters to be small (if <=10degrees) or to directly measure them if significantly non-zero (>=30degrees) using the technique of eclipse mapping."